# Showing a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally 1:1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

Before applying the inverse function theorem, we must show that it is locally 1:1.

I am confused by two things:

1) what exactly does it mean by "local"? How is it different from "global"?

2) What is the best way to show this?

For instance, consider:

$$F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \; F(x,y) = (e^y\cos(x), e^y\sin(x))$$

How would I show that this is locally 1:1, but not globally 1:1?

When I calculate the determinant of the jacobian, I get:

$|DF(x)| = -e^{2y}[\sin(x)\cos(x) + \cos^2(x)]$

But, I can see this is clearly singular for many points throughout the domain, namely whenever $x = \pi n - \frac{\pi}{4}$ - however, and correct me if I'm wrong, I have a feeling this is a CONSEQUENCE of the failure of "not globally one-to-one".

One thing I thought of was setting:

$F(x=a,y=b)$ and solving for:

$$e^b \cos(a) = e^y \cos(x) \; \; \cdots (1)$$
$$e^b \sin(a) = e^y \sin(x) \; \; \cdots (2)$$

For $(1):\; x = 2 \pi n - \cos^{-1}(\cos(a)), n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is clearly not globally 1:1. But what about locally?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Local means in the same city.  Global means in the same world.

Comment: @Michael  I get that much. But what I am unsure about is how to mathematically show this fact? Is it the case of finding some $\epsilon - \delta$ challenge-response?